# SwiftUi bottom left button dont show

Tags: swift, button, swiftui

I have some SwiftUI function. I want to show my button in bottom left, but it shows top left.

```
struct NewRecordButton: View {

    var body: some View {

        ZStack (alignment: .bottomTrailing) {
            HStack (alignment: .bottom) {
                Spacer()
                Button(action:  { },
                       label: {
                           Text("⌂")
                               .font(.system(.largeTitle))
                               .frame(width: 35, height: 30)
                               .foregroundColor(Color.white)
                               .padding(.bottom,4)
                })  .background(Color.black)
                    .cornerRadius(10)
                    .shadow(color: Color.black.opacity(0.3),
                            radius: 3,
                            x: 3,
                            y: 3)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although it's possible, **but** you should try **NOT** to use dummy views to arrange other views!

For pushing a view down, you should use a `VStack` and a `Spacer` together

```
VStack { 
    Spacer()
    // bottomView
}
```

So it should be like:

```
ZStack {
    VStack {
        Spacer() // This will push it down, since it is in a `VStack`
        HStack {

            Button("⌂") {}
                .font(.largeTitle)
                .frame(width: 35, height: 30)
                .foregroundColor(.white)
                .padding(.bottom, 4)

                .background(Color.black)
                .cornerRadius(10)
                .shadow(color: Color.black.opacity(0.3), radius: 3, x: 3, y: 3)

            Spacer() // This will push it left, since it is in a `HStack`
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I added your codes but shows white background under bottom about 30px height and full width, I want to remove it

Comment: That is safe area. `.edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)` will remove it if you apply it on the `VStack` or `ZStack`

Comment: I think you missed something. (maybe the last Spacer)

Answer (score 2):

Here is possible variant

```
ZStack (alignment: .bottomTrailing) {
    Rectangle().fill(Color.clear)
    HStack (alignment: .bottom){
        Button(action:  {

        }, label: {
            Text("⌂")
                .font(.system(.largeTitle))
                .frame(width: 35, height: 30)
                .foregroundColor(Color.white)
                .padding(.bottom,4)


        })
            .background(Color.black)
            .cornerRadius(10)
            .shadow(color: Color.black.opacity(0.3),
                    radius: 3,
                    x: 3,
                    y: 3)

        Spacer()
    }
}
```